# How do you mutate a column based on the values from another ID's columns, with specific time? (panel data)

Tags: dplyr

Here's an artificial dataset I'm working on:

```
     id year work spouse_work
1  1000 1999    1           1
2  1000 2001    1           1
3  1000 2003    1           1
4  1000 2004    1           0
5  1000 2005    0           0
6  1001 1999    1          NA
7  1001 2001    1          NA
8  1001 2003    1          NA
9  1001 2005    1          NA
10 2000 2001    1           1
11 2000 2003    1           1
12 2000 2004    1           1
13 2000 2005    0           1
14 2001 2001    1          NA
15 2001 2003    1          NA
16 2001 2005    1          NA
```

The first three digits of `id` represent the family, and the last digit of `id` represent the child ID in this family. If the last digit of `id` is 0, then this person is the family host. If the last digit of `id` equals 1,2,3, etc., then this person is the child of the host. In this dataset, `id=1000` and `id=2000` are the host, and `id=1001` is `id=1000`'s child, `id=2001` is `id=2000`'s child.

Now I want to create two new columns: `parent_1_work` and `parent_2_work`. For example, since `id=1001`'s parents' working status is already indicated in `id=1000`'s `work` column and `spouse_work` column, then we can fill in the values of `parent_1_work` and `parent_2_work` for `id=1001`, based on the values in `id=1000`'s `work` column and `spouse_work` column. Also note that it has to be year-specific. For example, `id=1001` doesn't have data in year 2004, therefore we cannot fit the value of `id=1000,year=2004,work=1` into `id=1001,year=2005,parents_1_work`.

The end result should be like this:

```
     id year work spouse_work parent_1_work parent_2_work
1  1000 1999    1           1            NA            NA
2  1000 2001    1           1            NA            NA
3  1000 2003    1           1            NA            NA
4  1000 2004    1           0            NA            NA
5  1000 2005    0           0            NA            NA
6  1001 1999    1          NA             1             1
7  1001 2001    1          NA             1             1
8  1001 2003    1          NA             1             1
9  1001 2005    1          NA             0             0
10 2000 2001    1           1            NA            NA
11 2000 2003    1           1            NA            NA
12 2000 2004    1           1            NA            NA
13 2000 2005    0           1            NA            NA
14 2001 2001    1          NA             1             1
15 2001 2003    1          NA             1             1
16 2001 2005    1          NA             0             1
```

Can someone please help?

Here's the code to create this artificial data. Much appreciated!

```
year<-c(1999,2001,2003,2004,2005,1999,2001,2003,2005,2001,2003,2004,2005,2001,2003,2005)
id<-c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1001,1001,1001,1001,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
work<-c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
spouse_work<-c(1,1,1,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA)
parent_1_work<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,0)
parent_2_work<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1)
before<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,year,work,spouse_work))
before
result<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,year,work,spouse_work,parent_1_work,parent_2_work))
result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Supplied sample data
year <- c(1999, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 1999, 2001, 2003, 2005, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2001, 2003, 2005)
id <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001)
work <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
spouse_work <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)
before <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, year, work, spouse_work))

# Code
after <- before |> 
  arrange(year, id) |> 
  mutate(family = str_sub(id, 1, 3),
         child = str_sub(id, 4, 4)) |> 
  group_by(year, family) |> 
  mutate(parent_1_work = if_else(child > 0, first(work), NA_real_),
         parent_2_work = if_else(child > 0, first(spouse_work), NA_real_)) |> 
  arrange(id, year) |> 
  ungroup()
  
after
#> # A tibble: 16 × 8
#>       id  year  work spouse_work family child parent_1_work parent_2_work
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1  1000  1999     1           1 100    0                NA            NA
#>  2  1000  2001     1           1 100    0                NA            NA
#>  3  1000  2003     1           1 100    0                NA            NA
#>  4  1000  2004     1           0 100    0                NA            NA
#>  5  1000  2005     0           0 100    0                NA            NA
#>  6  1001  1999     1          NA 100    1                 1             1
#>  7  1001  2001     1          NA 100    1                 1             1
#>  8  1001  2003     1          NA 100    1                 1             1
#>  9  1001  2005     1          NA 100    1                 0             0
#> 10  2000  2001     1           1 200    0                NA            NA
#> 11  2000  2003     1           1 200    0                NA            NA
#> 12  2000  2004     1           1 200    0                NA            NA
#> 13  2000  2005     0           1 200    0                NA            NA
#> 14  2001  2001     1          NA 200    1                 1             1
#> 15  2001  2003     1          NA 200    1                 1             1
#> 16  2001  2005     1          NA 200    1                 0             1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you. this solved the problem smoothly. seems like the key is arrange() and group_by(), and using first() is so smart. have a nice day :)